# My timestamps are created with the day after the date

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, timestamp, schema

I am creating a schema applying at the end {timestamps:true} so that mongo creates the fields 'createdAt' and 'updateAt' but when creating the document with a request, these two fields are created correctly except for the day, on the day of the date it is set the following day. I don't use these fields at all, I just keep them in the document as a record.
[image]
In the image you can see the two fields that are created automatically and in my taskbar the current date, which day does not match

Creating a schema with timestamps generates the wrong date, putting only the day after the current date

Comment: timezone mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

Those dates have an offset of `+00:00`, or zero hours. That means those date are in the UTC (or GMT) timezone.

Your local time zone is probably different. For example, if you are somewhere the americas during the evening it could be past midnight UTC time, which means its the next day. That's completely normal and expected.

If I make a date out that date string you posted, I get the following:

```js
console.log(new Date('2023-03-15T02:35:59.775+00:00').toString())
// Tue Mar 14 2023 19:35:59 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Note how the input string says `"03-15"` and the logged output says `"Mar 14"`.

I am on the west coast of the United States, meaning my local time zone is pacific time, which has an offset of -7 hours. The `Date` constructor in javascript knows to interpret that date string as +0 hours offset, and then translate it to my local time for me.

---

It's very common to store time in a database as +0 hours offset, or UTC. This is because your users may be anywhere in the world, and will need to have dates translated for them at some point, so storing them with an offset of zero is a logical neutral starting point.

So everything is fine, that is expected, you got the right timestamp because it's using a time zone that is very far from your location.

Comment: How could I solve this? Is there a way to change the time zone? or is it better to handle it the way it is saved? i am from colombia.

Comment: You don't "solve" this. This is not a problem. Why do you think it's a problem?